# can't access a returned object properties from a service by angular 2 data binding

Tags: javascript, json, angular

#### Process

I am using a service to get data (objects) from a json file with an observable and display them in the HTML template.

#### Problem

I can't access the objects properties by using `{{obj.prop}}`, it throws an error `"Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined".`
However if I try to access it in the component, it works.

#### Code

> ContentService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentContentService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getContent() {
   return this._http
     .get('./app/services/dataContent.json')
     .map((response:Response) => response.json())
     .do(response => console.log('response = ', response))
  }
}
```

> TopContentComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WowComponent } from '../libraries.components/wow.component/wow.component';
import { BackstretchComponent } from '../libraries.components/backstretch.component/jquery.backstretch.component';
import { ComponentContentService } from '../services/component.content.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'top-content',
  templateUrl: './app/top-content.component/top-content.component.html',
  directives: [WowComponent, BackstretchComponent]
})
export class TopContentComponent {
  header  : any;
  description : any;
  data : any;
  constructor(private _ComponentContentService: ComponentContentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {this.getComponentContent();}

  getComponentContent() {
    this._ComponentContentService.getContent()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.data = data;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

> Template

```
<p>{{data.header.title}}<p>
```

> JSON

```
{
  "header" : {
    "title":"Our New Course is Ready",
    "description" : "We have been working very hard"
  },
  "Footer" : {
    "title":"Our New Course is Ready",
    "description" : "We have been working very hard to create the new version of our course. It comes with a lot of new features, easy to follow videos and images. Check it out now!"
  },
}
```

Comment: Can you change `{{data.header.title}}` for `{{data?.header?.title}}` and check?

Comment: It might be that your template is trying to access that data before it is loaded from the json file, and so it is finding that "data" is still undefined

Comment: It works for {{data?.header?.title}} . thanks  a lot @OlegBarinov

Comment: no problems, just give a vote for an answer below and thanks for that )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change `{{data.header.title}}` for `{{data?.header?.title}}`

Comment: I couldn't find what's the question mark purpose in the docs, could you explain it briefly?

Comment: it adds checking for not null || undefined values before checking for fields after '.'
just prevents errors like `"Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined"`