# Angular 2 - Explanation for inconsistent behaviour when trying to access object properties using data service

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, interpolation

I have tried to frame this question in relation to the 3 examples in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/6k8o0QwcZOLqL86ilJoQ?p=preview). Hopefully it helps make the question clearer.

I have three arrays of data:

- `localHeroes` is defined in the app.component.ts
- `dbHeroes` is fetched from a database (Firebase) and data gets assigned to an empty array in the app.component.ts
- `dbHeroesPredefined` is fetched from a database and data gets assigned to a predefined array in the app.component.ts

*(again hopefully it’s clear what I mean from the plunk, but also pasting the relevant excerpts below)*

All sets of data can be displayed without issue using `*ngFor`.

## Accessing properties:

- `{{localHeroes[0].name}}` displays "Batman" as expected.
- `{{dbHeroes[0].name}}` errors with: `"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`. The expected result is for it to display "Iceman" (the name of the first hero in the `dbHeroes` array as seen below)*
- `{{dbHeroesPredefined[0].name}}` displays `Ironman`.

## Questions:

1. What is preventing me from accessing the `dbHeroes` data in the same way as `localHeroes` and `dbHeroesPredefined`?
2. Why does the `dbHeroes` example behave differently?
3. Is there a way to get `{{dbHeroes[0].name}}` to display without needing to pre-define the array that the data maps to, as in the `dbHeroesPredefined` example?

The complete example is available on this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/6k8o0QwcZOLqL86ilJoQ?p=preview). Really appreciate any help in understanding this.

**Footnote**:
Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041310/cant-access-a-returned-object-properties-from-a-service-by-angular-2-data-bindi), I guess using optional parameters `?` may be a way to solve the issue. Something like `{{dbHeroes?[0].name}}` did not help in this case, but as there was no explanation around that answer so I’d love to be clearer on the issue and solution.

`dbHeroes` array in JSON format:

```
dbHeroes: [
  {
    "name": "Iceman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Fireman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Postman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Angry Clive"
  }
]
```

`dbHeroesPredefined` array in JSON format:

```
dbHeroesPredefined: [
  {
    "name": "Ironman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pacman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sonywalkman"
  },
  {
    "name": "Intimidating Kenneth"
  }
]
```

app.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    dbHeroes?: any[]; 

    localHeroes: any[] = [
    {name: 'Batman'},
    {name: 'Spiderman'},
    {name: 'Dustinhoffman'},
    {name: 'The Incredible Dave'}
    ];

    dbHeroesPredefined: any[] = [
    {name: 'placeholder'},
    {name: 'placeholder'},
    {name: 'placeholder'},
    {name: 'placeholder'}
    ]; 
  
    constructor( private dataService: DataService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     
        this.dataService
          .getEntryData('dbHeroes')
          .subscribe(
            (dbHeroes:any) => 
            this.dbHeroes = (dbHeroes)
          );
          
      this.dataService
          .getEntryData('dbHeroesPredefined')
          .subscribe(
            (dbHeroesPredefined:any) => 
            this.dbHeroesPredefined = (dbHeroesPredefined)
          );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `dbHeroes` doesn't have a value assigned to it at the time Angular is resolving the bindings, but instead gets a value assigned only on later when the response from the server arrives.

You can work around with

```ts
<div *ngIf="dbHeroes">Sub in  {{dbHeroes[0].name}} results in failure </div>
```

or

```ts
<div>Sub in  {{dbHeroes && dbHeroes[0].name}} results in failure </div>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xaj9sIGQVHZsOkFde5Er?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Günter that’s extremely helpful. 
Would this always be the recommended workaround?
I ask as I had a similar issue trying to reload a form (and form values) that were accessing data from firebase(I suspect the same problem). 
I thought it was a dependency issue and that I might need to write a promise either in the dataService or appComponent that would 1) get data & assign values to an array THEN 2) resolve the bindings. Could this issue ever be solved with a promise or something similar? I ask as a novice so apologies if that's a stupid suggestion. thanks for your help

Comment: Usually `?.` is used but that is not supported for `[` only for `.` (like `dbHeroes?.someProp?.otherProp`